How to add filters to Pandas pivot table?
I'm trying to recreate a pivot table I made in Excel in Python using Pandas library. There's over 500k lines of OD total trips data that I'm trying to summarize with time period as the filter. On Excel I would just do row(O), column(D), values(trips), filter(time). So far on Python, I just have index, columns, values, aggfunc, but I don't know how to filter. There's 12 time periods and I only want to include 3.
I tried using O/D both as index, then time as column. Is there a way to remove columns from the pivot table?
Here is what I have that makes a full pivot table including all times:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('...xlsx')
print(df.pivot_table(index=['O', "D"], columns=['Time'], values=['Trips'], aggfunc='sum'))

I have also tried:
print(df[(df.Time == '7am')].pivot_table(index=['O', "D"], columns=['Time'], values='Trips', aggfunc='sum'))

This works for me, but I'm trying to include 3 different hours so I tried
print(df[(df['Time'] == '7am') & (df['Time'] == '4pm') & (df['Time'] == 'All Day')].pivot_table(index=['O', "D"], columns=['Time'], values='Trips', aggfunc='sum'))

But this didn't work.
I'm very new to Python, and admittedly, don't understand much. So please let me know if I need to become more knowledgeable in some aspect of Python to figure this out (or if it's incredibly basic). Or any resources that could point me in the right direction.

You just need to use OR | instead of AND &. The Time can't be both 7am and 4pm at the same time.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. I'm voting to close the question because you do actually know how to filter, you just made a mistake with the logic. In the future, try picking apart your code, like say, checking the number of rows that match your query (in this case, 0), like this: mask = (df['Time'] == '7am') & (df['Time'] == '4pm') & (df['Time'] == 'All Day'); print(mask.sum()). There are also some other tips here: How to make good reproducible pandas examples

Maybe you need to correct your knowledge of Boolean logic? I learned it at college myself so IDK any good tutorials.

In your code above:
print(df[(df['Time'] == '7am') & (df['Time'] == '4pm') & (df['Time'] == 'All Day')].pivot_table(index=['O', "D"], columns=['Time'], values='Trips', aggfunc='sum'))

You are saying to Pandas to search for three values at the same time. In your example you are searching for a row that has '7am', '4pm' and 'all day'. You are not saying to search for these different values along the column at different rows.
You can use the method isin() and put the filter at a variable.
like:
filtered_df = df[df['Time'].isin(['7am','4pm','all day'])]
pivot_table = filtered_df.pivot_table(index=['O', 'D'], columns=['Time'], values='Trips', aggfunc='sum')

I think it will work. I hope so

Use the | "or" operator instead of the & "and" operator:
df[(df['Time'] == '7am') | (df['Time'] == '4pm') | (df['Time'] == 'All Day')].pivot_table(index=['O', 'D'], columns=['Time'], values='Trips', aggfunc='sum')

However, since they're all in the same column, use the .isin method:
df[df['Time'].isin(['7am', '4pm', 'All Day']].pivot_table(index=['O', 'D'], columns=['Time'], values='Trips', aggfunc='sum')

